# How do I fix Pyautogui click and hotkeys not working?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm able to use other functions of pyautogui, such as moveTo, press and stuff, but I can't use .click and .hotkey in any IDE.
I also tried selenium and keyboard and it doesn't work at all.
Can anyone help me.

[Any variation of this function and .click don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxk59.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.  Please also include more context.  One line doesn't show how you set up your program.